# COreControls is not defined

Tags: javascript, pdftron

PDFTron customui I am trying get custom ui based on sample from PDFTron that they have provided online https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/guides/core/ however when I open the console I get that the CoreControl  CoreControls.setWorkerPath('wwwroot/lib/webviewer/core');  is not defined but its included in the solution. Could you please advice what am I missing

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}


<script>
CoreControls.setWorkerPath('wwwroot/lib/webviewer/core');

const docViewer = new CoreControls.DocumentViewer();

docViewer.setScrollViewElement(document.getElementById('scroll-view'));
docViewer.setViewerElement(document.getElementById('viewer'));
docViewer.loadDocument('lib/webviewer/simpleSign.pdf');
docViewer.setOptions({ enableAnnotations: true });

setupEventHandlers(docViewer);

docViewer.on('documentLoaded', () => {
    console.log('document loaded');
    // enable default tool for text and annotation selection
    docViewer.setToolMode(docViewer.getTool('AnnotationEdit'));
});

// setup event handlers for the header
const setupEventHandlers = docViewer => {
  document.getElementById('zoom-in-button').addEventListener('click', () => {
    docViewer.zoomTo(docViewer.getZoom() + 0.25);
  });

  document.getElementById('zoom-out-button').addEventListener('click', () => {
    docViewer.zoomTo(docViewer.getZoom() - 0.25);
  });

  document.getElementById('create-rectangle').addEventListener('click', () => {
    docViewer.setToolMode(docViewer.getTool('AnnotationCreateRectangle'));
  });

  document.getElementById('select').addEventListener('click', () => {
    docViewer.setToolMode(docViewer.getTool('AnnotationEdit'));
  });

  const annotationChangeContainer = document.getElementById('annotation-change');

  const annotManager = docViewer.getAnnotationManager();
  annotManager.on('annotationChanged', (annotations, action) => {
    annotationChangeContainer.textContent = action + ' ' + annotations.length;
  });
};

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported the `CoreControls.js` file in your page?

Comment: <script src="~/lib/webviewer/core/CoreControls.js"></script>

Comment: Could you attach the full error you saw in console?